# I'm lost in the JPanel, JFrame update and action listening

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, keylistener

Good day everyone! I just got back into programming, and I'm facing some problem with the construction of my code. What I'm trying to do is a menu for a future application that could help me and my friends when we play a certain board game.

So right now, I'm having difficulty to figure out how I should structure my code. I have 3 class planned so far. the Main class, which create a `JFrame`. a `MainFrame` class which help the main setup the frame, and finally the third class is `MainPanel`, which display the proper `JPanel` on the frame depending on the state of the program.

The plan `JPanel` classes are:

- a menu Panel, with 3 button on it: New, Load and Exit.
- a loading Panel, which just display "Loading" while the application load stuff (will be use when someone click New)
- a loadBoard Panel, which display the list of created board (when someone click Load)

I'm having 2 issue right now:

- Where do I fit the code to monitor the Key event (such as KeyListener on the frame, so independently of where I am at in the program, the program Exit when I press the Esc key.)
- How do I make sure the repaint() is handle properly? I have a problem where the Label "Loading" change location when I resize the window.

I know my code ain't construct ideally, that's why I'm posting this thread. I would like to better understand how to setup the code to have a similar result of what I have right now, but well construct.

This is my code:

MAIN Class

```
package test.project
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {      
        Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> 
        {         
            MainFrame theWindow = new MainFrame("Test",screenSize);
            theWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            theWindow.getContentPane().add(new MenuPanel(theWindow,theWindow.getSize()));
        });
    }
}
```

MAINFRAME Class

```
package test.project;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame
{
    @SuppressWarnings("LeakingThisInConstructor")
    public MainFrame(String windowName, Dimension theSize)
    {
        setTitle(windowName);
        setSize(theSize.width/2,theSize.height/2);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

MAINPANEL Class

```
package test.project;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel
{
    JFrame theHolder;
    public MainPanel(JFrame holder, Dimension theSize)
    {
        theHolder = holder;
        setSize(theSize);
    }
}

class MenuPanel extends MainPanel implements ActionListener
{
    JButton newButton = new JButton("NEW");
    JButton loadButton = new JButton("LOAD");
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("EXIT");    

    @SuppressWarnings("LeakingThisInConstructor")
    public MenuPanel(JFrame holder, Dimension theSize)
    {
        super(holder, theSize);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        SetButton(this);
        setVisible(true);
        theHolder.repaint();
    }

    private void SetButton(JPanel thePanel)
    {
        newButton.addActionListener(this);
        loadButton.addActionListener(this);
        exitButton.addActionListener(this);
        thePanel.add(newButton);
        thePanel.add(loadButton);
        thePanel.add(exitButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource().equals(newButton))
        {
            theHolder.getContentPane().remove(this);
            theHolder.getContentPane().add(new LoadingPanel(theHolder,theHolder.getSize()));
            theHolder.repaint();
         }
        if(e.getSource().equals(loadButton))
        {

        }
        else if(e.getSource().equals(exitButton))
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

class LoadingPanel extends MainPanel
{
    JLabel loadingLabel = new JLabel("LOADING");

    @SuppressWarnings("LeakingThisInConstructor")
    public LoadingPanel(JFrame holder, Dimension theSize)
    {
        super(holder, theSize);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        SetLabel(this);
        setVisible(true);
        theHolder.repaint();
    }

    private void SetLabel(JPanel thePanel)
    {   
        thePanel.add(loadingLabel);
        loadingLabel.setSize(thePanel.getSize());
        loadingLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        loadingLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is overly broad in that it isn't a single question. I suggest that you divide your questions up so that you ask one question per post, and show relevant code and information for that one question.

Comment: 1) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 3) `setVisible(true);
        theHolder.repaint();`  Panels default to visibility 'true' when the panel is added to a top level container that is made visible.  It seems that panel is never added to anything.  As such, calling `repaint()` on the frame is pointless.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well, I'm not sure how I could divide my code to make multiple post, since the big problem I think I have is overall code construction. Like: should I keep swaping JPanel in my JFrame, or should I just create 1 JPanel and actually modify it to fit the state of the application?

Comment: Tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson the Panel is add to the JFrame when it's created theWindow.getContentPane().add(new MenuPanel(theWindow,theWindow.getSize()));